# instead of finding flutter-debug.aar gradle try to find flutter-debug.jar

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

instead of finding flutter-debug.aar gradle try to find flutter-debug.jar

[image]

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

```
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[flutter_debug.pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEzMl.jpg)

I notice that the pom file missing debug/release variant subfix.

so, a bat can do this trick.

```
a.bat ${version_number} ${debug/release} ${path_to_file}
 ${artifactId}
```

[a.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpvJe.png)